# unity 5 how can I display stats of an class on a Character Creation menu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Making a game in Unity 5 and I have the Main-Menu, and CharacterCreation-Menu. However in the CharacterCreation-Menu I want it to display the "Warrior" stats and "Mage" stats once I click that class in the menu. How can I do so?

I realize that I can add more Menus with each class stats placed onto the screen with the UI text but that wouldn't be that very fun, also that I can add a new canvas for each player on the CharacterCreationg_Menu but that would make Everything so hard to see and very messy.

I have a hunch that I should add the necessery information in the "public void Warrior" and "public void Mage" But I cannot figure it out.

Once I press a class in the CharacterCreation_Script:
CharacterCreation-Menu_Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterCreationScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Class Info
    public Canvas classInfo;

    // Class Buttons
    public Button warrior;
    public Button mage;

    // Buttons
    public Button createCharacter;
    public Button goBack;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        classInfo = classInfo.GetComponent<Canvas>();
        classInfo.enabled = false;

        // Classes
        warrior = warrior.GetComponent<Button>();
        mage = mage.GetComponent<Button>();

        // Buttons
        createCharacter = createCharacter.GetComponent<Button>();
        goBack = goBack.GetComponent<Button>();
    }
    // Classes
    // Warrior
    public void Warrior()
    {
        classInfo.enabled = true;
    }
    // Mage
    public void Mage()
    {
        classInfo.enabled = true;
    }
    // Create Character Button
    public void CreateCharacter()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("NewGame");
    }
    // Go Back Button
    public void GoBack()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }
}
```

I get a text popping up on the screen "Class Info"
But it does not contain the information stored in the Player_Classes:

Warrior

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BaseWarriorClass : BaseCharacterClass
{

    public BaseWarriorClass()
    {
        // Basic
        CharacterClassName = "Warrior";
        CharacterClassDescription = "Uses melee to crush enemies.";
        //Gold = 100;

        // Stats
        Health = 100;
        Mana = 100;
        Stamina = 10;
        Strength = 20;
        Intelligence = 5;
        Armour = 0;
        Resistance = 0;
    }
}
```

Mage

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BaseMageClass : BaseCharacterClass
{

    public BaseMageClass()
    {
        // Basic
        CharacterClassName = "Mage";
        CharacterClassDescription = "Uses spells to vaporize enemies.";
        //Gold = 100;

        // Stats
        Health = 100;
        Mana = 100;
        Stamina = 10;
        Strength = 5;
        Intelligence = 20;
        Armour = 0;
        Resistance = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might just have a general UI element (the View) that shows the stats/abilities/description of any character class (the Model).

```
public class CharacterDetailsView : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text healthText;
    public Text manaText;
    // ...

    public void SetModel(BaseCharacterClass chr)
    {
        healthText.text = chr.Health.ToString();
        manaText.text = chr.Mana.ToString();
        // ...
    }
}
```

In your CharacterCreationScript you would not hide and show specific Canvases for each class, but you would just create different types of characters and pass them on to your view:

```
public class CharacterCreationScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterDetailsView characterDetailsView;
    private BaseCharacterClass createdCharacter;

    // ...

    void WarriorClicked()
    {
        createdCharacter = new BaseWarriorClass();
        UpdateCharacterDetailsView();
    }

    void MageClicked()
    {
        createdCharacter = new BaseMageClass();
        UpdateCharacterDetailsView();
    }

    void UpdateCharacterDetailsView()
    {
        characterDetailsView.SetModel(createdCharacter);
    }
}
```

You also have to make sure that your scene is setup correctly:

- Have a GameObject in your scene that represents the character details view area, and give it child Text ui elements matching those declared in the CharacterDetailsView class.
- Add the CharacterDetailsView script to your new GameObject and assign the child Text elements to their respective fields.
- Finally, you assign the GameObject to the characterDetailsView field in your CharacterCreationScript.

Even though there is still much room for improvement, this is much easier to maintain than having seperate UI elements.
You may want to read up on the Model-View-Control design pattern, which should be very helpful for any UI based game.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at the Model-View-Control :)

Comment: Whenever I have the "public UI.Text healthText;" I get an error saying that the type or namespace doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah yes, no errors now :) Thank you again. Gonna try and see if I can get those scripts to work with the buttons now.

Comment: Sorry for all these questions but I really cannot figure these things out myself, I learn as someone teaches... Kinda bad at Learning myself things. However, when I press one of the classes now, nothing displays.

Comment: I added a section about scene setup to my answer :-)

Comment: So far Everything works besides that the UI text elements cannot go inside the GameObject.

Comment: Make sure the GameObject is a child of a Canvas. You are on the right track when the GameObject has a RectTransform displayed in the UnityEditor. If in doubt, create a Panel (GameObject/UI/Panel in the menu) and use this as your GameObject.

Comment: Yes yes, very good indeed. It works very nicely. Thank you alot :D